# How to display a error for a form field when other field is touch?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two fields and a button, a simple button.

1. If I click the button and the fields are not both fill, this button will be disabled and in each field will be shown an error message is required.
2. When first field is touched and if I press the button the error message will be show but only for the first field, and to show the error for the second field I need to touch the field , but I need that if I press this button and both of the fields are not fill to show error message. And when I press the button and the fields are not both field only at the first one I get the error cause is touch but at the second no, this is what I want to get.

**HTML** :

```
<div *ngIf="data.softwareCategoriesRenderComponent === true ||  data.industry === true">
      <h4>Please write the {{data.itemName}} name in EN *.</h4>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [formControl]="name" required [(ngModel)]="data.newItemName" maxlength="20"
          (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
        <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">The  English name is required </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="dialog-margin">
        <span class="mat-body-1">Maximum of 50 characters</span>
      </div>
      <h4>Please write the {{data.itemName}} name in CZ *.</h4>
      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput [formControl]="nameCZ" required [(ngModel)]="data.newCZItemName" maxlength="20"
          (focus)="focusFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()">
        <mat-error *ngIf="!show">The  Czech name is required </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="nameCZ.invalid">The  Czech name is required </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div class="dialog-margin">
        <span class="mat-body-1">Maximum of 50 characters</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**TS:**

```
name = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  nameCZ = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  focusOutFunction() {
    if (this.data.softwareCategoriesRenderComponent === true) {
      if (this.name.valid && this.nameCZ.valid) {
        this.show = true;
      } else {
        this.show = false;
      }
    }
  }

  focusFunction () {
    this.show = true;
  }
```

Comment: try this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation)

Comment: is using div, you may see I want to use mat-error I don't have the opportunity to choose , but thank you

Comment: The link I have provided as a dupe should greatly help you with two methods to use validation on two controls. You will then have to adapt your code  (since your validation is different). If you have any issue when implementing your own code, feel free to ask a new question with the said issue, in a [mcve] preferably !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this demo you can easily understand by this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-template-driven-form

Comment: at begining i have said a simple button , means isn't a submit button , i know how to get that by submit or if i have a form group but the code i have here is all i have

Comment: in my code, if you touch and move in further then you can get an error without clicking submit button

Comment: and you can convert that submit button to simple then the result is the same no changes are there. just try once

Comment: if I touch I get the error  but not if i touch the first one and that i click the button i need a type of condition about it

Comment: you can not click the button because if  any field is empty then the button will not be clickable just check that

Comment: that's right i want a condition that if one of the fields is touch and not valid to show an error and this work for each of them but not for them together, the case if the first field is filled, when I remove focus the button is hidden now the problem is I don't get an error in this case because I need to touch the second field to get the error message

Comment: *ngIf="nameCZ.invalid || !show"  or  ngIf="name.invalid || !show" will be but isn't working